# What are the advantages of Hyperledger Fabric over Client-Server Model

Tags: client-server, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I have been searching but at the end the whole transaction process seems like Client-Server model with extra Blockchain steps.

Answer (score 0):

Peer-to-Peer model is a Client-Server model with extra steps to get the ip of the peers